# Why does Perl's Inline::C sort 4.0e-5 after 4.4e-5?

Tags: perl, sorting

I built a Perl [Inline::C](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Inline-C) module, but there is some oddity with the sorting.  Does anyone know why it would sort like this?  Why is the 4.0e-5 is not first?

```
my $ref = [ 5.0e-5,4.2e-5,4.3e-5,4.4e-5,4.4e-5,4.2e-5,4.2e-5,4.0e-5]; 

use Inline C => <<'END_OF_C_CODE';

void test(SV* sv, ...) {

  I32 i;
  I32 arrayLen;
  AV* data;
  float retval;
  SV** pvalue;

  Inline_Stack_Vars;
  data = SvUV(Inline_Stack_Item(0));

  /* Determine the length of the array */
  arrayLen = av_len(data);

  // sort 
  sortsv(AvARRAY(data),arrayLen+1,Perl_sv_cmp_locale);

  for (i = 0; i < arrayLen+1; i++) {

    pvalue = av_fetch(data,i,0);  /* fetch the scalar located at i .*/
    retval = SvNV(*pvalue);  /* dereference the scalar into a number. */

    printf("%f \n",newSVnv(retval));
  }
}

END_OF_C_CODE
```

> test($ref);

0.000042
0.000042
0.000042
0.000043
0.000044
0.000044
0.000040
0.000050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an answer with help from the people over at http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=761015

I ran some profiling (DProf) and it's a 4x improvement in speed

Total Elapsed Time = 0.543205 Seconds
  User+System Time = 0.585454 Seconds
Exclusive Times
%Time ExclSec CumulS #Calls sec/call Csec/c  Name
 100.   0.590  0.490 100000   0.0000 0.0000  test_inline_c_pkg::percent2

Total Elapsed Time = 2.151647 Seconds
  User+System Time = 1.991647 Seconds
Exclusive Times
%Time ExclSec CumulS #Calls sec/call Csec/c  Name
 104.   2.080  1.930 100000   0.0000 0.0000  main::percent2

Here is the code

```
use Inline C => <<'END_OF_C_CODE';

#define SvSIOK(sv) ((SvFLAGS(sv) & (SVf_IOK|SVf_IVisUV)) == SVf_IOK)
#define SvNSIV(sv) (SvNOK(sv) ? SvNVX(sv) : (SvSIOK(sv) ? SvIVX(sv) : sv_2nv(sv)))

static I32 S_sv_ncmp(pTHX_ SV *a, SV *b) {

  const NV nv1 = SvNSIV(a);
  const NV nv2 = SvNSIV(b);
  return nv1 < nv2 ? -1 : nv1 > nv2 ? 1 : 0;
}

void test(SV* sv, ...) {

  I32 i;
  I32 arrayLen;
  AV* data;
  float retval;
  SV** pvalue;

  Inline_Stack_Vars;
  data = SvUV(Inline_Stack_Item(0));

  /* Determine the length of the array */
  arrayLen = av_len(data);

  /* sort descending (send numerical sort function S_sv_ncmp) */
  sortsv(AvARRAY(data),arrayLen+1, S_sv_ncmp);

  for (i = 0; i < arrayLen+1; i++) {

    pvalue = av_fetch(data,i,0);  /* fetch the scalar located at i .*/
    retval = SvNV(*pvalue);  /* dereference the scalar into a number. */

    printf("%f \n",newSVnv(retval));
  }
}

END_OF_C_CODE
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you are sorting lexically, Try this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $ref = [ 5.0e-5,4.2e-5,4.3e-5,4.4e-5,4.4e-5,4.2e-5,4.2e-5,4.0e-5]; 

print "Perl with cmp\n";
for my $val (sort @$ref) {
    printf "%f \n", $val;
}

print "Perl with <=>\n";
for my $val (sort { $a <=> $b } @$ref) {
    printf "%f \n", $val;
}

print "C\n";

test($ref);

use Inline C => <<'END_OF_C_CODE';

void test(SV* sv, ...) {

  I32 i;
  I32 arrayLen;
  AV* data;
  float retval;
  SV** pvalue;

  Inline_Stack_Vars;
  data = SvUV(Inline_Stack_Item(0));

  /* Determine the length of the array */
  arrayLen = av_len(data);

  // sort 
  sortsv(AvARRAY(data),av_len(data)+1,Perl_sv_cmp_locale);

  arrayLen = av_len(data);
  for (i = 0; i < arrayLen+1; i++) {

    pvalue = av_fetch(data,i,0);  /* fetch the scalar located at i .*/
    retval = SvNV(*pvalue);  /* dereference the scalar into a number. */

    printf("%f \n",newSVnv(retval));
  }
}

END_OF_C_CODE
```

Of course, lexically `0.00040` is smaller than `0.00042` as well, but you aren't comparing `0.00040` to `0.00042`; you are comparing the number `0.00040` converted to a string with the number `0.00042` converted to a string.  When a number gets too large or small, Perl's stringifying logic resorts to using scientific notation.  So you are sorting the set of strings

```
"4.2e-05", "4.2e-05", "4.2e-05", "4.3e-05", "4.4e-05", "4.4e-05", "4e-05", "5e-05"
```

which are properly sorted.  Perl happily turns those strings back into their numbers when you ask it to with the `%f` format in `printf`.  You could stringify the numbers yourself, but since you have stated you want this to be faster, that would be a mistake.  You should not to be trying to optimize the program before you know where it slow (premature optimization is the root of all evil`*`).  Write your code then run [Devel::NYTProf](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-NYTProf/) against it to find where it is slow.  If necessary, rewrite those portions in [XS](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxstut.html) or `Inline::C` (I prefer XS).  You will find that you get more speed out of choosing the right data structure than micro-optimizations like this.

`*` [Knuth, Donald](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/). [Structured Programming with go to Statements](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=356640), [ACM Journal Computing Surveys](http://surveys.acm.org/), Vol 6, No. 4, Dec. 1974. p.268.

Comment: I would like to have the sorting in the Inline::C section for speed.  This may be the problem, but how to get sortsv() to sort numerically is not well documented.

Comment: You won't get any speed out of it.  The sort function in Perl is written in C.

Comment: Now, if you mean the function you are _passing_ to the sort function, that may get a speed boost, but it would have to be pretty complicated.

Answer (score 2):

`Perl_sv_cmp_locale` is your sorting function which I suspect is lexical comparison. Look for numeric sorting one or write your own.

Comment: This is not well documented in the perl api.  Even trying to try and write my own function no luck.